# Android Dialog animation

Tags: android, animation, dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Animate a custom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817014/animate-a-custom-dialog)

in my app i'm using some custom dialogs that are displayed fullscreen.
I want to change the default dialog animation but i can't figure out with that.

How can I do that?

Thank you