# How to change position of Alert Dialog

Tags: android, animation

I have an android application uses Alertdialog.I am setting animation for this dialog.I want to start the animation from top left and ends at bottom right.ie,The dialog want to moves  from top-left to bottom-right with in the animation duration time.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Refer this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817014/animate-a-custom-dialog

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Final Result");
        alert.setMessage(msg);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });


        // dlgAlert.create();
        AlertDialog dialog_card = alert.create();
        // dlgAlert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP =
        dialog_card.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

        dialog_card.show();`
```

Comment: This code shows dialog always at top.But i want the dialog is at bottom when the animation finishes.

Comment: change top to bottom it will bring dialog to bottom. Accept if work

Comment: Do you know is it possible to more than one gravity for a dialog?

Comment: @Asha: To set up more than one gravity here is how:
dialog_card.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP| Gravity.LEFT);