# how to apply animation on a dialog box?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am having a dialog box which opens on a button click.I want to put animation on the dialog box like it is coming from up to down etc.
I applied overridePendingTransition but it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, Did you apply the override immediately *after* starting the activity? i.e;

        startActivity(blah.class);
        overridePendingTransition(anim1, anim2);

That caught me out once. Failing that- post some code.

Comment: actually what ever you want is here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817014/animate-a-custom-dialog