# Fade out splash screen without using intent

Tags: view, webview, splash-screen

So I recently added a splash screen to my app without using any other activities as most of my searching has found.

Everything works as it should, but my goal is to have it fade out to my view being loaded, preferably after my view loads since its a webview.

What would be the best way to accomplish the fade out animation of the splash screen, WITHOUT using a separate activity and intent?

Below is my working code in my main activity.

```
package com.chris.myapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.chris.myapp.adapter.ActionsAdapter;
import com.chris.myapp.fragment.WebViewFragment;
import shared.ui.actionscontentview.ActionsContentView;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String STATE_URI = "state:uri";

    private ActionsContentView viewActionsContentView;
    private MyPagerAdapter pageAdapter;
    private Dialog mSplashDialog;

    private Uri currentUri = WebViewFragment.DEFAULT_URI;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyStateSaver data = (MyStateSaver) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if (data != null) {
            // Show splash screen if still loading
            if (data.showSplashScreen) {
                showSplashScreen();
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.example);        

            // Rebuild your UI with your saved state here
        } else {
            showSplashScreen();
            setContentView(R.layout.example);
            // Do your heavy loading here on a background thread
        }

        viewActionsContentView = (ActionsContentView) findViewById(R.id.actionsContentView);
        viewActionsContentView.setSwipingType(ActionsContentView.SWIPING_EDGE);
        viewActionsContentView.setSpacingType(ActionsContentView.SPACING_ACTIONS_WIDTH);
        viewActionsContentView.setSpacingWidth(650);
        viewActionsContentView.setActionsSpacingWidth(0);

        pageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        pager.setPageMargin(20);
        pager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.color.pager_bg);

        final ListView viewActionsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.actions);
        final ActionsAdapter actionsAdapter = new ActionsAdapter(this);
        viewActionsList.setAdapter(actionsAdapter);
        viewActionsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                    long flags) {
                final Uri uri = actionsAdapter.getItem(position);
                updateContent(uri);
                viewActionsContentView.showContent();
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentUri = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_URI));
        }

        updateContent(currentUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString(STATE_URI, currentUri.toString());

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public void updateContent(Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null)
            return;

        final WebViewFragment webViewFragment = (WebViewFragment)
        pageAdapter.getItem(MyPagerAdapter.WEBVIEW_FRAGMENT_POSITION);
        webViewFragment.setUrl(uri.toString());
        webViewFragment.reload();
        currentUri = uri;
    }

     /**
     * Removes the Dialog that displays the splash screen
     */
    protected void removeSplashScreen() {
        if (mSplashDialog != null) {
            mSplashDialog.dismiss();
            mSplashDialog = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the splash screen over the full Activity
     */
    protected void showSplashScreen() {
        mSplashDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.SplashScreen);
        mSplashDialog.setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        mSplashDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mSplashDialog.show();

        // Set Runnable to remove splash screen just in case
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    removeSplashScreen();
                }
            }, 3000);
    }

    /**
     * Simple class for storing important data across config changes
     */
    private class MyStateSaver {
        public boolean showSplashScreen = false;
        // Your other important fields here
    }


    private static long back_pressed;
    private Toast toast;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final WebViewFragment currentFragment = (WebViewFragment)
                pageAdapter.getItem(MyPagerAdapter.WEBVIEW_FRAGMENT_POSITION);
        if (currentFragment instanceof WebViewFragment) {
            final WebViewFragment webFragment = currentFragment;
            if (webFragment.onBackPressed())
                return;
        }

        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis())
        {

            // need to cancel the toast here
            toast.cancel();

            // code for exit
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
        else
        {
            // ask user to press back button one more time to close app 
            toast=  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            viewActionsContentView.showContent();
        }
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you using a dialog as your splash screen you could add an animation to the dialog, probably look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817014/animate-a-custom-dialog?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring this out with the code below. Hope it helps somebody out.

```
  public void removeSplashScreen() {
          if (mSplashDialog != null && mSplashDialog.isShowing()) {
            final MainActivity that = this;
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                AnimationListener animationListener = new AnimationListener() {

                  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    that.mSplashDialog.dismiss();
                    that.mSplashDialog = null;
                  }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                };
                AlphaAnimation splashDismissAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
                splashDismissAnimation.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
                splashDismissAnimation.setDuration(750);  // Gives app some time to init.

                View view = ((ViewGroup) ((Dialog) that.mSplashDialog).getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView()).getChildAt(0);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                view.startAnimation(splashDismissAnimation);
              }
            };
            this.runOnUiThread(runnable);
          }
        }
```