# slide in animantion onCreate android

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, view

I am trying to slide in a custom dialog just after the activity is created. but each time dialog comes along with the activity. I want to show the dialog after the activity is created.
Have tried creating the dialog in `onCreate()`, `onResume`, `onPostResume`.

Dialog creation :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.PauseDialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Test Dialog Transition");
        dialog.show();
```

animation style :

```
<style name="PauseDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/PauseDialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="PauseDialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Looks like you're following the code from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817014/animate-a-custom-dialog/5591827#5591827   Are you sure you have Animations enabled on your device?

Comment: not just that answer have tried couple of others as well. Yes animation is on on my device. I can see slide_out animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I could find to delay the transition was by using Handler. I used postDelayed() to delay transition of the dialog.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.PauseDialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Test Dialog Transition");
        dialog.show();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer to include a boolean to determine if we have shown the dialog yet to avoid showing multiple times.**

This appears to work correctly.

> Called when the current Window of the activity gains or loses focus. This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible to the user.

```
boolean mDialogShown = false;   

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    if(!mDialogShown)
    {
        mDialogShown = true;

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.PauseDialog);

        dialog.setTitle("Test Dialog Transition");
        dialog.show(); 
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

Comment: this is not the correct way as the dialog will can keep on getting recreated even after dismissing it. Since onWindowFocusChanged() will be called as after dialog is dismissed.

Comment: will be a problem if we use it fragments especially when multiple fargments are loaded at the same time.