# Animate dialog without using XML file?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialogfragment

I would like to animate a dialog dynamically (dialog may translate up or down to exit) through code ? is it possible to implement?

Comment: may be this could help a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817014/animate-a-custom-dialog

Comment: @aakash Actually i don't want to work on xml files. In xml files we can declare only one exit animation for a dialog. But in my case, based on the option user selects it will have different exit transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Look the link below. It will help you.

[Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)