# How do i "bring" an selected view centered in "front"?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, user-interface

Im currently trying to achieve the following :

[image]

Once one of the four card views in the background is selected it should appear in the middle of the screen... in other words ... it should come in front of everything else.

Is there an easy way to achieve this ?

Comment: Create a dialog or create a layout over the four card layout with the transparent backgroud . But dialog would be a much simpler approach

Comment: @RohitSingh Is there also a way to add some animation to it ? For example that it flys to the center ?

Comment: Yep you can search for how to animate a Fragment(If you are planning to make it using transparent background).

Comment: I have never tried animating Dialog but here is a related question i guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817014/animate-a-custom-dialog (If you are planning to do this with dialog)

Comment: See this link : https://github.com/alibaba/UltraViewPager

Comment: You probably looking for the view transition with animation have a look at this [animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android](https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50)